# How to remove selected special characters from DataFrame column in Python

Tags: python, pandas, special-characters

I am merging different excel files into a csv file. Values in one of the columns(Length) in the source files contain single quote (e.g. '200, '50 etc.). Some values can also contain a period at the end(e.g. '200., '50., '10.3 etc.). I want to to remove only the single quote from the values.

**Input**

```
Length
=======
'2000

'100.

'10.3
```

**Desired output**

```
Length
=======
2000

100.

10.3
```

I am using the following code but somehow it also removes period(.) from the values. Please help.

```
import pandas as pd
import glob

path= input("Enter the location of files ")

GLB_DM_VER = input("Enter global DM version")

GLB_DM_ENV = input("Enter the global DM version environment")

file_list = glob.glob(path+"\*.xls")

excels = [pd.ExcelFile(name) for name in file_list] 

frames = [x.parse(x.sheet_names[2], header=0,index_col=None) for x in excels]

combined = pd.concat(frames)

**combined['LENGTH'].replace(regex=True,inplace=True,to_replace=r'\'',value=r'')**

combined.to_csv("STAND_2.csv", header=['Global_DM_VERSION_ID','Global_DM_VERSION_ENV','TARGET_DOMAIN','SOURCE_DOMAIN','DOMAIN_LABEL','SOURCE_VARIABLE','RAVE_LABEL','TYPE','VARIABLE_LENGTH','CONTROL_TYPE','CODELIST_OID','TARGET_VARIABLE','MANDATORY','RAVE_ORIGIN'], index=False)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with:

```
df['length'].str.replace("'","")
```

This will remove all the single quotes in the column